# How do I insert new line in a variable to crate Qrcode

Tags: php

I am trying to create business card QRcode that contains employee picture

```
        if (file_exists($employeeBCpicture))    {
        
    $imagedata = file_get_contents($employeeBCpicture);
    $photo64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
}else {//echo 'No<br>';
}
    // QR bind_textdomain_codeset
    //Include the necessary library for Ubuntu
    include_once('/usr/share/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    //Set the data for QR
    $text =
    'BEGIN:VCARD'. "\n".
    'VERSION:2.1.'. "\n".'
    N:'.ucwords($rowe['lname']).';'.ucwords($rowe['fname']).';;;'. "\n".'
    FN:'.   $fullname. "\n".'
    TEL;WORK:+'.$phoneline. "\n".'
    TEL;CELL:+'.$mobile. "\n".'
    EMAIL;WORK:'.$email. "\n".'
    URL;WORK:'.$website. "\n".'
    ORG:'.ucwords($rowc['companyname']). "\n".'
    TITLE:'.$title. "\n".'
    ADR;WORK:;;'.$address.';;'. "\n";
if ($photo64 != ''){
$text = $text.'PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=BASE64:
'.$photo64.' '. "\n".' '
. "\n".' '
. "\n".' ' ;
}
    $text = $text.'
END:VCARD';
    //Set the filename with unique id
//echo $text.'<br>';
    $rfilename = '../../../signatures/'.uniqid().".png";
        //Set the error correction Level('L')
    $e_correction = 'L';
    //Set pixel size
    $pixel_size = 2;
    //Set the frame size
    $frame_size = 2;
    //Generates QR image
    QRcode::png($text, $rfilename, $e_correction, $pixel_size, $frame_size);
```

my problem is the \n is not working and it is necessary to add new lines
the QR code works when  the following section is commented (to remove the photo section)
the photo section needs three \n 3 new lines to work
also I will need to add new lines to format the business card

```
if ($photo64 != ''){
$text = $text.'PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=BASE64:
'.$photo64.' '. "\n".' '
. "\n".' '
. "\n".' ' ;
}
```

My problem is the php variable $text is giving me inline output and I need to separate the lines before using the QRcode function

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the string quoting. As you want to use a line return `\n`, it is best to keep the entire grouping in [double quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

If I have understood what you want to do, I think this should work:

```
if ($photo64 != ''){
    $text = $text."PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=BASE64:\n".$photo64." \n \n \n";
}
```

And you could / should possibly do this instead:

```
if ($photo64 != ''){
    $text = "${text}PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=BASE64:\n${photo64} \n \n \n";
}
```

More details can be found on the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) and even on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Comment: Thanks that was very useful 
now I created a working vcf file successfully 
but I have the problem mentioned here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569202/php-qrcode-generation-failed