# How do I embed images in a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, qr-code

This is a related question to a post I made a few weeks ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209512/how-can-i-generate-a-qr-code-containing-data-from-a-dataframe-in-r). I am trying to embed QR codes in a new column in a list of dataframes. The QR code will contain the numerical result from the other column and can be scanned into our lab information system. Thus far i am able to generate a dataframe with a column containing QR codes using RMarkdown, but I can't seem to do it when I try to adapt this code to a list of dataframes.

Here is an example of what does what I want with a single dataframe:

````
---
title: "QR Code in Column"
author: "dorton"
date: "2019/01/20"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r mychunk1, fig.show = "hide", echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, out.width="72px", include=TRUE}
library(knitr)
library(qrcode)

test <- LETTERS[1:10]
result.one <- round(rnorm(1:10),2)
df <- data.frame(test, result.one, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$result.one <- as.character(df$result.one) #qrcode_gen needs a character input    

invisible(lapply(df$result.one, function(x) qrcode_gen(x)))

out <- cbind(as.character(df$test), 
             as.character(df$result.one), 
             include_graphics(sprintf("![](%s%s-%s.png){width=72px}", 
                                 opts_current$get("fig.path"), 
                                 opts_current$get("label"), 
                                 1:nrow(df))))
kable(out, col.names = c("ID", "Text", "Code"))
```
````

In reality, I have a list of dataframes containing "results" for "test" A-J. What I want is to loop through the list of dataframes and embed QR codes in each dataframe, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Here is an example of an attempt that doesn't work:

````
```{r mychunk, fig.show = "hide", echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, out.width="72px"}

library(knitr)
library(qrcode)

test <- LETTERS[1:10]
result.one <- round(rnorm(1:10),2))
result.two <- round(rnorm(11:20), 2)
df1 <- data.frame(test, result.one, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(test, result.two, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$result.one <- as.character(df1$result.one)
df2$result.two <- as.character(df2$result.two)
colnames(df1) <- c("test", "result")
colnames(df2) <- c("test", "result")

df.list <- list(df1, df2)

for (i in length(df.list)){
  invisible(lapply(df.list[[i]]$result, function(x) qrcode_gen(x)))

  out <- cbind(as.character(df.list[[i]]$test), 
             as.character(df.list[[i]]$result), 
             include_graphics(sprintf("![](%s%s-%s.png){width=72px}", 
                                 opts_current$get("fig.path"), 
                                 opts_current$get("label"), 
                                 1:nrow(df.list[[i]]))))
}

  for (i in df.list){
  cat("\n\\newpage\n") #This is to add a page break between output tables. I would like to use a pdf output, but I'm not stuck on it.
  kable(out.qr, col.names = c("Test", "Result", "Code"), caption = paste0("Sample ID"))
}

```
````

I have tried a few different iterations of the second code chunk. I expect that it has something to do with where the png's that I am generating with the `invisible(lapply(df.list[[i]]$result, function(x) qrcode_gen(x)))` are being saved, but i can't seem to figure out an alternative. Can I generate a list of lists for the pngs? Do I have to?

Any help is much appreciated, and I'm not stuck on using `rmarkdown` either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a little difficult to figure and the soultion might not be as elegant as possible. But it works. If I find some time tomorrow Ill try to get deeper into it.

Notice that qrcodes are numbered from 1 to the total number of rows in all data frames. So we have to take care of this using the counter `total` and save the number of codes per dataframe when creating them (in `nums`).

---

````
---
title: "QR Code in Column"
author: "dorton"
date: "2019/01/20"
output: pdf_document     
---


```{r mychunk, echo = FALSE, fig.path =  "qr/", results = 'asis', fig.show='hide'}
library(knitr)
library(qrcode)
df.list <- list(A = data.frame(result = as.character(rnorm(2)),                    
                               test = LETTERS[1:2], stringsAsFactors = F),
                B = data.frame(result = as.character(rnorm(2)),
                               test = LETTERS[3:4], stringsAsFactors = F))

nums <- invisible(sapply(df.list, function(df) {
  lapply(df$result, qrcode_gen)  # create qrcode
  nrow(df)                       # save number of rows of df
}))

path <- paste0(opts_current$get("fig.path"), opts_current$get("label"), "-")

total <- 0
for(i in seq_along(nums)) {
  out <- cbind(df.list[[i]]$test,
               df.list[[i]]$result,
               paste0("![](", path, (1:nums[i]) + total, ".pdf){width=72px}")) 

  print(kable(out))
  total <- total + nums[1] 
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. So simple... What's the reason for not using `sprintf`?

Comment: Nevermind, had something in mind that in the end was incorrect. `sprintf` is fine to use as well.