# Create QR Code for direct download using .NET Core

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, qr-code

Is it possible to generate a qr code in .net and when scanning it, it automatically downloads a pdf document instead of going to a url?

Example:

```
string myBase64Pdf = "base64code.....";

QRCodeGenerator _qrCode = new QRCodeGenerator();      
QRCodeData _qrCodeData = _qrCode.CreateQrCode(myBase64Pdf,QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);  //error maximun length    
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(_qrCodeData);      
Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);  

var htmlcontent = await repository.getTemplateHtml();
htmlcontent = htmlcontent.Replace("||QRSection||", qrCodeImage); //error but qrCodeImage must be 
string
//htmlcontent = htmlcontent.Replace("||QRSection||", qrCodeImage.ToString()); ???

var mybase64Pdf = util.ConvertHtmlToPDF(htmlcontent);
```

but in this line:
`QRCodeData _qrCodeData = _qrCode.CreateQrCode(myBase64Pdf,QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);`

I've exception:

> The given payload exceeds the maximum size of the QR code standard. The maximum size allowed for the choosen paramters (ECC level=Q, EncodingMode=Byte) is 1663 byte.

Comment: Point the URL to the PDF?

Comment: I edit post, but 've exception when pass base64 string

Comment: Read the exception message.  What you are trying to embed is too big.  It looks like you're trying to embed the PDF?  That won't work.

Comment: so i can't insert a file? must it be a url?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065415/how-much-data-information-can-we-save-store-in-a-qr-code

Comment: You can embed binary data in a QR code but it will probably only be readable by a program that knows what to expect. How big is your PDF file?

Comment: The problem is made worse by base64-encoding the data, making the payload ~33% bigger.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen : the pdf size is 58.6kb but when i convert to bytes the size bytes is: 9617

Comment: @AlonsoContreras Once that has been base64-encoded, it will be 76kb.  That is more than three times as big as what the largest QR code can handle.  Even if you don't base64-encode it, it's still double the max capacity of a QR code.  QR codes are not designed to send files like this.  You can link to the file online, or turn your PDF into a small image, but those are the options.

Comment: @Amy So it is not possible to store a file inside a QR? The other solution I have is to put a url with the resource id and that the page is in charge of taking that file according to the id that I will send it.

Comment: @AlonsoContreras The thing you are trying to put in the box is larger than the box.  If you can make your PDF smaller than the box, it will fit.

Comment: @AlonsoContreras https://i.imgur.com/VLwJ7g9.jpg

Comment: @Amy hahahahah i understand!!

Comment: Thank you all!! I will find another way to generate my qr

Comment: The biggest binary you can put in a QR is 2953 bytes, and that is the biggest QR there is, with the lowest redundancy setting. You simply can't generate a QR to hold 9617 bytes, let alone 58.6Kb.