# How to compress a file to a qr code without using external libraries?

Tags: javascript, python, qr-code, offline

Is it possible to compress (not link) a file (as example, an excel file) to a qr code?
I want to extract a file from a computer without connecting it to the internet and without plugging a usb drive to it.

Did it with python but it only linked to the file, i want the qr code it self to the file.

Comment: A QR code can hold about 3KB. So you can only do this if the file can be compressed down to that size.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065415/how-much-data-information-can-we-save-store-in-a-qr-code

Comment: As for why you just got a link instead of the file contents, that sounds like a bug in your code. Show what you wrote.

Comment: You need to use `file.read()` to get the file contents, then encode that.

Comment: An empty excel file with no data is around 4kb - bigger than what QR code can contain. There are encodings that can convert digital data like excel files to something printable (for example see: https://github.com/cyphar/paperback) but the excel file will be compiled (not compressed but expanded) to several A4 pages. Generally printing the file as a table will use less paper than encoding the file in a QR-like format.